# Spring Data JPA ManyToOne Bidirectional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Problem: it works till i try to add Student obejcts to Database, but the tables are being created correctly .
I can't simplify the post any further. But it's mainly code that doesn't require a lot of reading, it's a simple spring data repository service model. I posted it all due to the fact idk what am i doing wrong. Problem is in the JPA mapping.
I got the example from over here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToManyBidirectional.htm

MDOELS

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Collection<Student> students;

    public Department() {
    }

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String deptName) {
        this.name = deptName;
    }

    public Collection<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudent(Collection<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Department id: " + getId() +
                ", name: " + getName();
    }
}



@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Department department;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, Department department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n\nID:" + id + "\nName:" + name + "\n\n" + department;
    }
}
```

REPOSITORIES

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> {
    Department findByName(String name);

}

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
    Student findByName(String name);
}
```

SERVICES

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;

    }

    public void addToDatabase(Student student) {
        this.studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);

    }

    public Student getStudentByName(String name) {
        return studentRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
@Service
public class DepartmentService {
    private final DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DepartmentService(DepartmentRepository departmentRepository) {
        this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;

    }

    public void addToDataBase(List<Department> department) {
        this.departmentRepository.save(department);
        department.forEach(this.departmentRepository::saveAndFlush);
    }
    public Department getDepartmentByName(String name){
        return  this.departmentRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

My main method

```
@Component
public class Terminal implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final StudentService studentService;
    private final DepartmentService departmentService;

    @Autowired
    public Terminal(StudentService studentService, DepartmentService departmentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
        this.departmentService = departmentService;
    }

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
            Department department = new Department("dep1");
            Department department1 = new Department("dep2");
            Department department2 = new Department("dep3");
            Department department3 = new Department("dep4");
            List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(department, department1, department2, department3));
            this.departmentService.addToDataBase(departments);
    //
            Student student = new Student("pesho", department);
            Student student11 = new Student("gosho", department1);
            this.studentService.addToDatabase(student11);
            this.studentService.addToDatabase(student);
            student = new Student("sasho", department2);
            this.studentService.addToDatabase(student);
    //        System.out.println(this.studentService.getStudentByName("gosho").getDepartment1());
    //        System.out.println("CHECKING ONE TO ONE BIDIRECTIONAL: " + this.departmentService.getDepartmentByName("dep1").getStudent());

        }
    }
```

So here when i try to add students in the students table it gives an error 
The error is the fallowing

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: app.models.Department
```

Comment: Who is the owner of the relationship?

Comment: a foreign key from student to department. Is there any place i can learn spring **boot** data with JPA

Comment: Can you add `@JoinColumn` on top of Department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you added cascade= CascadeType.ALL for Department in Student class and save departments separete. `this.departmentService.addToDataBase(departments);`

fix : dont call

```
departmentService.addToDataBase(departments);
```

or remove CascadeType.ALL from Student

Comment: why is everyone in their examples adding cascade type and when i add it it breaks everything?

Comment: it didn't break all , you add cascade type and try to manage departments. you mixed two concepts. if you add only cascade  it should works. also it should works if you work only with departments separatly from students (don't try to save departmets during saving students)

Comment: do you have example where they have cascade typies and managed cacsadede entity at the same time ?

Comment: sbjavateam i first add departments then students? in my main method

Comment: you first add departments and then save to hibernate - save this department when you save student , hibernate see that departments are already exist and they are detached from persistence context

Comment: in example that you have http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToManyBidirectional.htm  in Main class student is saved - em.persist(student); but there is no the same for department , there is no em.persist(dept). department  is created as a part of student

Comment: " in Main class student is saved - em.persist(student)" did not notice that. Ok so it worked if i add them like this. But what i want to add a department when a new department appears and then add students separatly ? and still maintain that bidirectional connection or is it impossibble. Ye so i just remove cascade type as you said.. got it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148540/discussion-between-sbjavateam-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't understand you problem completely but here's what I would like to add. Cascading for add operation is not implemented or it's incomplete. Hope it helps.

Comment: can i invite to chat in stackoverflow for a second to explain cascade type to me pls

Comment: Well Cascade type annotation is used on relationship's to automatically perform operation like insert delete on their child relation entities.